# web scraping: beautifulsoup

Tags: html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract all "Places of Interest" from Wikipedia pages using beautiful soup and Python/Pandas and put them into a dataframe. For example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1st_arrondissement_of_Paris

```
url_Paris_01 = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1st_arrondissement_of_Paris').text
soup_Paris_01 = BeautifulSoup(url_Paris_01, "html.parser")

for headline in soup_Paris_01.find_all("span", {"class": "mw-headline"}):
    print(headline.text)
```

---

```
Geography
Demography
Historical population
Immigration
Quarters
Economy
Education
Map
Cityscape
**Places of interest**
Bridges
Streets and squares
See also
References
External links
```

---

does not work

```
soup_Paris_01.find_all('li',attrs={"id":"Places_of_interest"})
```

I see that my "Places of Interest" all have a title tag.

Places of interest

- [Parc des Buttes Chaumont](/wiki/Parc_des_Buttes_Chaumont)
- [Parc de la Villette](/wiki/Parc_de_la_Villette)
- [Parc de la Butte-du-Chapeau-Rouge](/wiki/Parc_de_la_Butte-du-Chapeau-Rouge)
- The [Cent Quatre](/wiki/Cent_Quatre) arts centre

Comment: You asked few questions before and got useful answers but you didn't accept any of them, why?

Comment: Hi. I am new to stackoverflow. I wasnt sure how to accept them. I will do it now.

Comment: something like soup_Paris_01.find_all('li', {'class': None}, {'id':'Places_of_interest'}) works but I now want to limit my results as per the wikipedia page and also 'Places_of_interest' is not exact (containing) since some wikipages have 'Places_of_interest in the arrondissement'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find the `ul` item under `place of interest` span tag and then do **find_all()** for all anchor tag under `ul` item.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url_Paris_01 = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1st_arrondissement_of_Paris').text
soup_Paris_01 = BeautifulSoup(url_Paris_01, "html.parser")
placeofinterset=soup_Paris_01.find("span",id="Places_of_interest").find_next('ul')
for place in placeofinterset.find_all('a'):
    print(place['title']) #This will give you title
    print(place.text) #This will give you text
```